# Python: Printing ASCII Art Problems

Tags: python, printing, ascii

I'm attempting to print a piece of ASCII art in Python. I'm aware there are options such as ASCIImatics, but for my first milestone I'm just trying to get this piece to display properly in the terminal.
This presents some issues to be addressed:
-I want to make it possible to modify the contents of the lines, and I read that to do that lists must be used instead of regular strings.
-With the way print statements are structured in Python, I find it trickier to get the characters of a line to print on the same line. I read this requires the format
    print(line1[x], end=" ")

I'm still having trouble getting a loop to print my work properly. Although the lines print properly with regular print statements, adding the new formatting messes up the arrangement of the characters.

Here's something that looks like my code:

```
line0 = list("     ----    ")
line1 = list("    $$$$$$   ")
line2 = list("   !=!=!=!=  ")

for num in range(1,13):
    print(line0[num], end=" ")
    print(line1[num], end=" ")
    print(line2[num], end=" ")
```

I want it to print essentially as you see it in the code, but the spacing is wrong.
I suspect the

```
end=" "
```

parts don't work because I have to print spaces. What should I do?

Comment: What you have here should print your lines all on the same line, separated by spaces.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: No. I want to make that stack of characters.

Comment: Well, do you understand that setting `end` to `" "` is telling `print` not to end the lines with a newline, but to instead end them with a single space, so that the next `print` continues where it left off?  I suggest completely removing all of the `end=" "` arguments and trying again.

Comment: Stefan, it's because my next step will be to look through the lines for a specific character and replace it with another one (decided by user input).

Comment: If I remove the
   end=" "
parts, the chars print only one per line.

Comment: Okay, could you please read what I wrote before downvoting?

Comment: I'm trying to get all the characters of each line to print on the same line. Line1 would have all its characters on one line, and then Line2 would have all its characters on the line right below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the solution, no thanks to you guys.

```
txt = ''
for item in line0:
   txt += str(item)
print(txt)
```